# How to enabled extended attributes in UBIFS for SELinux?

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, selinux, xattr, ubifs

I am trying to run SELinux `chcon` command on a UBIFS root filesystem and I get `chcon: failed to change context of '/' to 'system_u:object_r:root_t': Operation not supported`. I understand SELinux needs filesystem support for extended attributes. For Linux kernel <3.4, `CONFIG_UBIFS_FS=y` will enable extended attributes for UBIFS by default.

I read from [here](http://www.linux-mtd.infradead.org/doc/ubifs.html#L_xattr) that `xattr` should automatically be enabled without additional mount options.

> Extended attributes
>   UBIFS supports extended attributes if the corresponding configuration option is enabled (no additional mount options are required). It supports the user, trusted, and security name-spaces. However, access control lists (ACL) support is not implemented.
>
> Note, currently mkfs.ubifs ignores extended attributes and does not write them to the target file-system image.

I am building the image using Yocto, and added `xattr` to DISTRO_FEATURES as well. What am I missing here?